# How do you limit apps to iPhones only and not iPods [iPhone SDK]?

Tags: iphone

There used to be an option in the submit wizard where you can specify whether your app is for iPhone, iPod or both. Now the option is gone for 3.0. Then I noticed an extra option in info.plist "Application requires iPhone environment". I checked this item but the app is still marked as iPhone and iPod in the portal. Any ideas? Couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: may I ask: why do you need to do this, btw?

Comment: I would assume because there are features that are only available on the iPhone and not one the iPod, Camera, GPS etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you finish your application and submit it to Apple for approval, there's a form on iTunes Connect where you can specify which devices it is compatible with. Many apps that use the camera, for example, are marked as iPhone-only. I'm not sure how they're handling the new 3G S, but there's definitely a way to limit the app to the iPhone only.

I think the item in the Info.plist is talking about Mac OS X v. iPhone, not iPod v. iPhone.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes there used to be an option on the form but not it's removed for 3.0 submission. Any ideas?

Comment: hmm - really? I'm not sure, then - I haven't submitted a 3.0 app yet... You might want to call developer support and ask - it's probably the fastest way to find out.

Answer (score 1):

The "Overview" page of the "Add New Application" wizard in iTunes Connect should have a "Device" dropdown after the "Application Name" and "Application Description" fields (it's the 3rd field from the top). Is that where you're looking?

Comment: Like I said, that option is only there if you click "no" to "Was this binary compiled on the iPhone OS 3.0 SDK or later?". If you click yes, the option goes away!

Answer (score 0):

They may have taken it out because it didn't really work anyway.  Someone could buy from iTunes any app and only at installation time would they find it was restricted from being run on a Touch...

Just make it as clear as you can in your description what you require.